# PyQt set enabled property of a row of QComboBox

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, python-2.7, pyqt4

How can I set the enabled property of a row of a `QComboBox`? I want it to have some disabled and some enabled rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a working example of a QComboBox, where items 1 and 4 (as specified in the list `disable`) are disabled. I used [this](http://theworldwideinternet.blogspot.nl/2011/01/disabling-qcombobox-items.html) example. See also the documentation for the [setData](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qabstractitemmodel.html#setData) method.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import sys

class Foo(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        items = ['foo', 'bar', 'yib','nuz', 'pip', 'rof']
        cb = QtGui.QComboBox(self)
        for i in items:
            cb.addItem(i)

        disable = [1,4]
        for i in disable:
            j = cb.model().index(i,0)
            cb.model().setData(j, QtCore.QVariant(0), QtCore.Qt.UserRole-1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    foobar = Foo()
    foobar.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Compatibility note: if you're using PySide rather than PyQt, replace `QtCore.QVariant(0)` with `0`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29975498/446302), we can simplify Junuxx's answer to :

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
import sys


class Foo(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        items = ['foo', 'bar', 'yib', 'nuz', 'pip', 'rof']
        cb = QtGui.QComboBox(self)
        for i in items:
            cb.addItem(i)

        disable = [1, 4]
        for i in disable:
            cb.model().item(i).setEnabled(False)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    foobar = Foo()
    foobar.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

Add each `QComboBox` from a row to a list, then work through the list setting the state.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import sys

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()                
        self.create_combos()

    def create_combos(self):
        widget = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)   

        # Create combo boxes and add them to a list.
        self.combo1 = QtGui.QComboBox()
        self.combo2 = QtGui.QComboBox()
        self.combo3 = QtGui.QComboBox()
        self.combobox_row = [self.combo1, self.combo2, self.combo3]

        # Create a toggle button and connect it to the toggle method.
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton('Toggle')
        self.button.setCheckable(True)
        self.button.setChecked(True)
        self.button.toggled.connect(self.enable_combobox_row)

        # Create layout.
        vbox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(self.combo1)
        vbox.addWidget(self.combo2)
        vbox.addWidget(self.combo3)
        vbox.addWidget(self.button)
        widget.setLayout(vbox)

    def enable_combobox_row(self, enabled):
        # Work through combo boxes and set the passed enabled state.
        for combobox in self.combobox_row:
            combobox.setEnabled(enabled)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainwindow = MainWindow()
    mainwindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: This solution made more sense before the question was edited ;).

Comment: Do you mean you interpreted the question as 'a row of comboboxes'? I hadn't thought of that. After seeing my edit to the question, what do you think is more likely?